# Easily convert multiple attribute columns from text to integer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, text, sorting, integer

I uploaded a CSV with WKT polygon coordinates. Each polygon was displayed spatially and I re-saved the file as a shapefile.

The problem is most attribute columns are being detected as text, and they should be numeric, integer values. This causes problems when sorting the data.

There are about 100 columns that are incorrectly classified as text.

Is there a way to easily convert all of them to integer?

I am using QGIS 2.18.15.

Comment: Among attribute fields you have, is there any you want to keep as text?

Comment: @Kazuhito No, I would prefer all of the attribute fields to be integer.

Comment: Then experts here may suggest scripts to solve this issue efficiently and quickly. I thought I would suggest MMQGIS `text to float` (it does not give you integer, though).

Comment: @Kazuhito What does MMQGIS text to float do?

Comment: In short, it converts text to floating point number. Please visit [MMQGIS website](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) for details.